# How to use the iPhone X faceID data

Tags: ios, face-id, truedepth-camera

Is it possible to use iphone X faceID data to create a 3D model of the user face? If yes, can you please give tell me where should I look? I was not reallw able to found something related to this. I found a video on the WWDC about true depth and ARKit but I am not sure that it would help.

**Edit:**
I just watched a WWDC [video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/601/) and its says that ARKit provides a detailed 3D geometry face. Do you think it's precise enough to create a 3D representation of a person face? Maybe combined with an image? Any idea?

[image]

Comment: No, just like the fingerprint data, the faceId data is stored in the secure enclave where it is not available to the main processor. If you are talking about using the sensors to map visuals to the users face in real time, then that is possible using ARKit.

Answer (score 6):

Yes and no.

Yes, there are APIs for getting depth maps captured with the TrueDepth camera, for face tracking and modeling, and for using Face ID to authenticate in your own app:

- You implement Face ID support using the LocalAuthentication framework. It's the same API you use for Touch ID support on other devices — you don't get any access to the internals of how the authentication works or the biometric data involved, just a simple yes-or-no answer about whether the user passed authentication.
- For simple depth map capture with photos and video, see [AVFoundation > Cameras and Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture), or the [WWDC17 session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/507/) on such — everything about capturing depth with the iPhone 7 Plus dual back camera also applies to the iPhone X and 8 Plus dual back camera, and to the front TrueDepth camera on iPhone X.
- For face tracking and modeling, see [ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit), specifically [`ARFaceTrackingConfiguration`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arfacetrackingconfiguration) and related API. There's [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_face_based_ar_experiences) showing the various basic things you can do here, as well as the [Face Tracking with ARKit](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/601/) video you found.

  Yes, indeed, you can create a 3D representation of a user's face with ARKit. The wireframe you see in that video is exactly that, and is provided by ARKit. With ARKit's SceneKit integration you can easily display that model, add textures to it, add other 3D content anchored to it, etc. ARKit also provides another form of face modeling called blend shapes — this is the more abstract representation of facial parameters, tracking 50 or so muscle movements, that gets used for driving avatar characters like [Animoji](https://vimeo.com/241348683).

  All of this works with a generalized face model, so there's not really anything in there about identifying a specific user's face (and you're forbidden from trying to use it that way in the App Store — see §3.3.52 "If your application accesses face data..." in the [developer program license agreement](https://developer.apple.com/terms/)).

No, Apple provides no access to the data or analysis used for enrolling or authenticating Face ID. Gaze tracking / attention detection and whatever parts of Apple's face modeling have to do with identifying a unique user's face aren't parts of the SDK Apple provides.